# How to prevent individual App Volume settings from going down?

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

From time to time, I notice that for example YouTube volume is very low. I try turn up the volume, but then realize that my system volume is already pretty loud. Then I go to "Sound Mixer Options", and find the App Volume for Google Chrome suddenly being *way* down:

[image: screenshot]

It's also happened to other apps. Clicking the Reset button makes all the App Volume settings go back to normal.

This keeps happening, and I don't understand why! When I use the media controls to change volume, it's always the Master volume that changes, as far as I can see. When changing the volume via the volume button in the systray, it's also the Master volume; it doesn't even show the App Volume. Same with the volume buttons on my bluetooth headset, they also, as far as I can see adjust the Master volume.

What is it that makes these individual App Volume settings go down? How can I prevent that from happening? Does Windows have some keyboard shortcuts I don't know about and accidentally press? Is there some integration Chrome or other apps have with the Windows sound system I don't know about?

Comment: Do you have any device connected to your system that has a volume knob on it

Comment: These are individually set (not Windows responsibility). Do you have a Chrome extension doing this?  Are you inadvertently setting Chrome volume lower for some reason?

Comment: @John I'm using a [Volume Master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-master/jghecgabfgfdldnmbfkhmffcabddioke) extension in Chrome, to boost audio _beyond_ 100, but fiddling around with that has no effect on the App Volume in Windows, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Ramhound Not that I'm aware of. At least not any knobs I'm using.